# Allowing access to Sharepoint online for AD user with no O365 account

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory

Recently, we were migrated from SP2013 to Sharepoint online, and we encountered a following problem:

We have "users" in AD which are basically just accounts for machines with no user interaction. As such, they don't have O365 account, e-mail etc. In old Sharepoint you could simply add them to site's permissions and it would work - now, even though they are added, SP still requires to login with e-mail account.

How can we make it so such an account has access to a folder in library to dump files in there?

Comment: Are you uploading those files programmatically?

Comment: The machine is managed by custom vendor software, where we can put a link to sharepoint so the results are saved in that location. On SP2013 we just added the AD user to SP Group and it worked - now it does not.

Comment: SharePoint OnPremises and SharePoint Online differ a lot in authentication. You will get a much more precise answer here, if you provide the upload-code. If it's a closed-source 3rd party software, please contact vendor for support.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the latter option. We did call for support, but they do not support SharePoint Online and can't provide a solution. The decision to migrate was not made by us, you know how it is in big corps, we have to deal with it somehow. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could migrate the users from Active directory to Azure Active Directory.

More references:

[Configuring SharePoint Online to Use Active Directory Users.](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/migrate-to-office-365-part2)

[How to sync local Active Directory to Office 365 with DirSync.](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/sync-premises-ad-office-365/)

[How to sync on-premises Active Directory to Azure Active Directory with Azure AD Connect.](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-sync-on-premises-active-directory-to-azure-active-directory-with-azure-ad-connect/)

Comment: Azure is not an option (our corp is actually actively blocking any Azure services, even for testing) - and I do not have the power to make such decision.